# UITableView subtitle not appearing

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have this simple code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithString: @"All about the color "];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=subtitle;
    cell.textLabel.text = [authorList objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that my subtitle doesn't appear.What am i doing wrong.Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You'll have to choose another cell style, look at the documentation:

> **UITableViewCellStyleDefault**
>
> A simple
> style for a cell with a text label
> (black and left-aligned) and an
> optional image view. Note that this is
> the default style for cells prior to
> iOS 3.0.

What you want, I think, is:

> **UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle**
>
> A style
> for a cell with a left-aligned label
> across the top and a left-aligned
> label below it in smaller gray text.
> The iPod application uses cells in
> this style.

You can refer to the Table View Programming Guide for iOS chapter [Table View Styles and Accessory Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html) to see an overview of the styles and what they look like.